# Cortana skill wasn't triggered by the invocation phrase

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service, cortana

I created a Azure based Web App Bot using the QnAMaker template and used the 'Test in Web Chat' to test it successfully. To enable voice assistant to the chatbot, I configured the Cortana channel and enabled the 'manage used identity through connected service' option too to link the user's account with the skill.

The chatbot wasn't published yet but same Microsoft account has been used in test devices to login to Cortana as the botframework login used to develop the Azure web app bot. However, the invocation phrase doesn't invoke the skill in the Cortana apps running on iOS, Android and Windows 10 PC.

I used utterance such as 'Ask purple genie', 'Tell purple genie' only to get the regular search results.

I changed the language/region to English/US on all the test devices too. Isn't this change enough for testing this skill when the device is not in US.

Comment: Does it work if you disable "manage user identity through connected service"? Also, did you go through the process of giving Cortana permission to use your skill? On Android it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGdgU.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/oE25V.png

Comment: Cortana for Android was recently updated from 3.0 to 3.1 but if that contained a breaking change it's hard to imagine it would affect all three platforms like that

Comment: It didn't work after disabling  "manage user identity .." option. I am not sure how to give Cortana permission to use my skill. Could you point me how to do this?

Comment: My Android phone has Cortana App 3.1.0.

Comment: Cortana should ask for permission automatically when your skill is reached the first time, so that still just seems to indicate that Cortana isn't finding your skill. Have you tried invoking the skill in languages other than English?

Comment: Thanks @KyleDelaney for you suggestion. I didn't try with any other languages as the documentation specifies Cortana skill kit is only available for en - us. http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/skills/faq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be a question of whether web search or skill has the priority in Cortana skill. In the chat I had with Micromuncher from Microsoft, he worked with his dev team to bring the skill invocation phrase to invoke the skill. Apparently Cortana dev team play around with setting priority of phrases to bring up search results instead of invoking a skill.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you did all the right things.
1/ Region must be US (and restart)
2/ Language must be US
3/ The MSA used to create the bot is the same as the channel
4/ The account used to invoke is the same MSA (check via Cortana notebook)

As a work around, try publish to group and add your MSA email there.  If, subsequently you can invoke the skill, let me know.

(Also, try invoke by voice AND try invoke by typing "ask myskill to do seomthing".)

Comment: Both are very good suggestions. I did push the skill to a group and added my email with no luck. I tried both text and voice having read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/skills/faq that voice support proceeds text support for Cortana skills.

Comment: Does the region where the skill (e.g. Web Bot App and other related Resources) gets deployed in Azure matter? My skill is deployed in East Australia.

Comment: the deployment region should not matter; but you likely need to restart a w10 device after changing region - if you published to group and you still cannot invoke the skill with the invocation name - send an email to skillsup at microsoft dot com with the email address, invocation name, and any other info to help triage - the only other time I've seen this is where a client forgot to press the deploy button :-)

Comment: I should also add if the region doesn't support Cortana skills, you'd see that behavior - double check your region settings.

Comment: And, you don't need to set up connected services (unless you are using OAuth to connect to MS graph or something).  If you do, the first thing you'd see after getting the skill permission page is an oauth login card.

Comment: I did click the deploy button ever time a change is made. My users must link their account to the skill but I have disabled it until the invocation issue is sorted out. I want to check the region of my skill though. If it is not the deployment region, I need to figure out how to check it in the Azure portal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184720/discussion-between-micromuncher-and-chandana-kithalagama).

Comment: It turns out to be a question of whether web search or skill has the priority in Cortana skill. In the chat I had with @Micromuncher he worked with his dev team to bring the skill invocation phrase to invoke the skill. Apparently Cortana dev team play around with setting priority of phrases to bring up search results instead of invoking a skill.